# android gps lagging

Tags: android, gps

i got this gps reciever method, which store's some data into a database.

```
// GPS
    private void addGPSListener() {
        globalconstant.db.setVersion(1);
        globalconstant.db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        globalconstant.db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    final String gps =

    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GPS_Values ("

            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Latitude float(10, 8), Longitude float(10, 8),Accuracy INTEGER,Speed INTEGER,City TEXT,timestamp TIMESTAMP);";
    globalconstant.db.execSQL(gps);


    float f = Float.valueOf(globalconstant.gps_update_value.trim())
            .floatValue();
    Log.d("FESTIVALE :: ", "Frissítési idő: "
            + f);
    float update = f;


    globalconstant.mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    globalconstant.mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    globalconstant.mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (long) update, 0,
            globalconstant.mlocListener);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        float szel = (float) loc.getLatitude();
        float hossz = (float) loc.getLongitude();
        int horiAcc = (int) (loc.getAccuracy());
        // int speed=(int) ((loc.getSpeed()*3600)/1000); //sebesség km/h-ban
        int speed = 0;

        if (loc.hasSpeed()) {
            speed = (int) ((loc.getSpeed() * 3600) / 1000); // sebesség
                                                            // km/h-ban
        } else {
            speed = 0;
        }

        String test = String.format("%.08f", szel);
        String test2 = String.format("%.08f", hossz);

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(main.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(szel, hossz,
                    1);
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ContentValues gps_values = new ContentValues();

        gps_values.put("Latitude", test);
        gps_values.put("Longitude", test2);
        gps_values.put("Accuracy", horiAcc);
        gps_values.put("Speed", speed);
        gps_values.put("City", city);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        gps_values.put("timestamp", dateFormat.format(date));

        try {
            globalconstant.db.beginTransaction();
            globalconstant.db.insert("GPS_Values", null, gps_values);
            globalconstant.db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            globalconstant.db.endTransaction();
        }

        Log.d("FESTIVALE :: ", "Hely " + test + ", " + test2 + " , "
                + horiAcc + " , " + speed + " , " + city + "," + dateFormat.format(date));
        // String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = "
        // + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude = " + loc.getLongitude();

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hely" +test + "\n" +
        // test2 + "\n" + horiAcc + "\n" +speed + "\n" +city,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    // show gps otions
                    Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    dialog.cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main.this);
        builder.setMessage("A GPS nincs aktiválva!\nAktiválja most?")
                .setPositiveButton("Aktivál", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Nem", dialogClickListener).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}// gps vége
```

the avarege update time is 1 sec. But my phone get's lagging (galaxy s2)i can see it because there's a chronometer.

Does anyone have any idea about why?

Comment: What do you mean by lagging?  GPS acquisition, CPU, ...?

Comment: the hole apk... as i said i can see in the chronometer steps usally 1, and if gps it steps 3-5 or more

Answer (score 1):

i think i got the solution:

```
globalconstant.mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (long) update, 0,
                globalconstant.mlocListener);
```

after the 'update' it stands a '0'. and heres what i found:

```
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

that means the min Distance was '0' so this is why it was so 'laggy'.
But thank you for anyone!

Answer (score 0):

GPS is VERY processor intensive.  It does not surprise me that your phone slows.  This is not unusual.

In fact, if you leave the GPS on long enough your phone will get hot and the battery will drain very rapidly!

Comment: hmm...that means i have to incrase the update time from 1sec -maybe- to 2 or 5?

Comment: Maybe.  But, be careful.  I have found that using high-power with periodic checks to be better than low-power constant GPS usage.  Better for battery and considerably better acquisition.